# PHAsset identifier persisting across devices

Tags: ios, icloud, phasset, photosframework

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34590338/icloud-sync-of-images-in-photos-framework-created-album), and according to (among others) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28690304/phasset-or-alasset-cross-device-identifier), the localIdentifier of a PHAsset doesn't persist across devices (after the photo syncs over iCloud).

**How can I store a reference to a PHAsset (image) that will persist across devices?**

Locally I store the localIdentifiers in an array so I can easily fetch the assets when needed, As the localIdentifiers dont persist across devices this obviously won't work. I don't want to store the actual image as this obviously has storage implications, and I wouldn't be able to use the Photos framework for things like easily loading thumbnails etc.

Is there any other way to get around this?

Comment: I have pretty much the same requirement. For the moment - as i don't see another existing way i will be taking a md5/sha1 hash of the image data and using this as an unique identifier - may be you can do something similar.

Answer (score 2):

I knew it is quite old question, but Apple announced `PHCloudIdentifier`  recently. It works great!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phcloudidentifier